# Working with Gson json strings in .NET

Tags: android, .net, json, gson, jayrock

I have an android phone app that has to exchange data with an asp.net web api service.  I've chosen to use JSON.  In the phone app I serialize objects into GSON JSON strings.  Now on the server I need to convert the gson json strings back into objects.

What should I use on the server side?  I have seen older posts that say Jayrock is the way to go.  Is it?

I'll be serializing and deserializing on both sides.  Also I've heard there are some issus with dates.
Thanks, Gary

Comment: to L.B, Barak, S.L. Barth, Florent,Nik... et al; It appears you don't want questions that solicit technical opinions.  I know you have to walk a line here but in this case I believe you do damage.  Fortunitely, I got a good answer before you did your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the JSON.net library. It works nicely. Here's the link: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx